# Lazy WebAPI object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, lazy

I am working to design an object which would abstract away the use of a WebAPI. I want the developer to be able to use these objects as if they are using a traditional API.

My **core problem** is how to abstract the interactions with the WebAPI. I currently use an Interface which is initialized in each element to provide basic calls. I am wondering if the element itself should implement the interface or if it should be an object within my class.

For now I am using the new Lazy object to restrict requests to their first use. I understand that this will require a more recent version of .Net.

```
public class AFElement : LazyPI.BaseObject
{
    private AFElementTemplate _Template;
    private Lazy<AFElement> _Parent;
    private Lazy<IEnumerable<AFElement>> _Children;
    private Lazy<IEnumerable<AFAttribute>> _Attributes;
    private IAFElement _ElementLoader;

    #region "Properties"

        public AFElementTemplate Template
        {
            get
            {
                return _Template;
            }
        }

        public AFElement Parent
        {
            get
            {
                return _Parent.Value;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<AFElement> Children
        {
            get
            {
                return _Children.Value; 
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<AFAttribute> Attributes
        {
            get
            {
                return _Attributes.Value;
            }
        }
    #endregion


    #region "Constructors"

        private AFElement()
        {

            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            string parentPath = Path.Substring(0, Path.LastIndexOf('\\'));

            //Load Template 


            //Load Parent
            _Parent = new Lazy<AFElement>(() =>
            {
                AFElement ele = _ElementLoader.FindByPath(parentPath);
                return ele;
            }, System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

            _Attributes = new Lazy<IEnumerable<AFAttribute>>(() => 
            {
                return _ElementLoader.GetAttributes(this.ID).Cast<AFAttribute>().ToList();
            }, System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

            _Children = new Lazy<IEnumerable<AFElement>>(() =>
            {
                return _ElementLoader.GetElements(this.ID);
            }, System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
        }
        // Initialized all basic references
        //Strips element name from path to get parent path

    #endregion
}
```